# Add Virtual products to cart with custom options programmatically

Tags: cart, custom-options, virtual

I am working on the virtual products add to cart.  I had written my custom code for add to cart and called the function on ajax call.Below is the code for the addtocart

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($proid);
$_product->setIsRecurring('1');
$_product->setRecurringProfile(array(
    'start_date_is_editable' => 0,
    'schedule_description' => "Test",
    'suspension_threshold' => 1,
    'bill_failed_later' => 1,
    'period_unit' => day,
    'period_frequency' => 12,
    'period_max_cycles' => 1
));

$_product->save();
    $params = array(
        'product' => $proid, // This would be $product->getId()
        'qty' => 1,
);

$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($_product,$params);
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Now when i am adding this product to cart i am getting following error.

a:5:{i:0;s:46:"Please specify the product required option(s).";i:1;s:1227:"#0

when i had looked why this is happening i had found that i had specified custom options for the products and it is specified as Required.Please See Below Image.

[image]

see the product page.this is not the default product page of magento. the product page is as follow

[image]

how can i set the selected custom option value to cart.which is required.

Please Help Me.

I tried many solutions but not worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To add product with required custom option to cart you need your `$params` array to be like this

```
$params = array(
    'product' => $proid, // This would be $product->getId()
    'qty' => 1,
    'options' => array(
        'option_id' => 'option_value'
    )
);
```

Where

**option_id**    - custom option id

**option_value** - selected custom option value

This will help you to get all product custom options data

```
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $option) {
    print_r($option);
    $values = $option->getValues();
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        print_r($value);
    }
}
```